# Correction of FWER for multiple "AND" tests?

Tags: statistics, significant-figures

For X to be considered valid, X needs to pass all *K* statistical tests, at p < 0.01 each. If X fails **any** statistical test, the null hypothesis is retained.

*K* however changes for different X.

In some cases, X needs to pass 10 statistical tests.

In other cases, X needs to pass 100 statistical tests.

Adjusting for FWER, if *K* = 10, the adjusted *alpha* is $10^{-2}$. If *K* = 100, adjusted *alpha* = $10^{-3}$.

I would like to have a constant FWER across different X.

Is there any way to correct *p* for multiple "AND" comparisons? It's been extremely difficult researching this topic since almost all online content is about correcting for Alpha risk inflation (whereas here Alpha is deflated).

The obvious solution would be doing a "reverse Bonferroni" correction, and multiply *p* by the number of comparisons. i.e., to have a FWER of 0.01, I would multiply the original Alpha (= 0.01) by the number of comparisons.

For K = 10 comparisons, the adjusted significance threshold would be < 0.1. Except for K = 100 comparisons, the adjusted threshold would be 1... Something's not right.

Are there papers that discuss of Alpha risk correction where significance is defined as passing all *K* tests?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The real problem here is I would guess the tests are not independent.  If they were independent, then you might argue that to have a $5\%$ chance of significance on all the tests under the null hypothesis, you would need to set the margin at $\sqrt[n]{0.05}$ (or 1 minus that) for significance on each test, where $n$ is the number of independent tests

Comment: @Henry Indeed, it wasn't that. I've deleted my comment to avoid confusing people. Do you happen to have sources/citations for the $\sqrt[n]{0.05}$.
correction? For n = 2 and p = 0.05, the corrected threshold would become 0.22, which I find to be slightly too high.

Comment: Your are correct that $\sqrt{0.05}\approx 0.22$.  If you had two *independent* tests which each flagged a result with probability $0.22$ then the probability both would be flagged a result is $0.0484$.  But you have would need a good reason to believe the tests would be independent, and that is why people do not make this adjustment